# Date/month/year-based filtering

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Can we have a feature to **filter Stack Overflow questions and answers based on the year** and date it was posted/edited (like dd/mm/yyyy)?

It will enhance the relevance of result, since APIs, technologies, and everything is undergoing a drastic change, and **currently a lot of results are deprecated**.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: @Mat yes.Its there .But it is not user friendly & it will took time to do such search every time.

Comment: You mean the search function is not intuitive or user friendly? No... say it ain't so...